# PHP/Mysqli - insert array of records if record does not already exist or return failure information

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, json

I want to insert x records into a table where each record consists of the following columns: name, abc, user_id & portfolio_id

I'm sending the information via ajax dataloader in json like this:

JSON

```
{"add":{"abc":"123","name":"CompanyName","user_id":"1","portfolios":[{"portfolio_id":"1"},{"portfolio_id":"2"},{"portfolio_id":"3"}]}}
```

... so I would like to insert:

```
abc|name|user_id|portfolio_id

123|CompanyName|1|1
123|CompanyName|1|2
123|CompanyName|1|3
```

How to insert those records with an array?

Comment: Usually, when you want to do something with an array, you are doing it in a loop

Comment: By any chance ... could you provide a Solution or more information?